# https calls from multiple lambda functions

Tags: aws-lambda

I am learning AWS lambda and have a basic question regarding architecture with respect to managing https calls from multiple lambda functions to a single external service.

The external service will only process 3 requests per second from any IP address.  Since I have multiple asynchronous lambdas I cannot be sure I will be below this threshold.  I also don't know what IPs my lambdas use or even if they are the same or not.

How should this be managed?

I was thinking of using an SQS FIFO queue, but I would need to setup a bidirectional system to get the call responses back to the appropriate lambda.   I think there must be a simple solution to this, but I'm just not familiar enough yet.

What would you experts suggest?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit about your system?  While you can restrict the number of Lambdas running this may not be the best setup.  You could have an input and output SQS queue but that sounds more complicated than may be needed.

Comment: What happens if the rate is exceeded? Can the calling functions simply try again?

Comment: What about if same ip give 2 call , do u have any corelation id like uuid or any other unique key to iddentify unique message request response ?

Answer (score 0):

- If I am understanding your question correctly then
- You can create and API Endpoint by build an API Gateway with Lambda integrations(preferred Lambda proxy integration) and then use throttling option to decide the throughput this can be done in different ways [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html) account level, method level etc.
- You can perform some load testing using gatling or any other tool and then generate a report for eg. which can show that even if you have say 6tps on your site you can throttle at method level and see that the external service is hit only at say 3tps.
- It would depend upon your architecture how do you want to throttle I had done method level to protect the external service at 8tps.